# Kivy Setting height for a Spinner Dropdown with many values

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown, spinner

In this code, I need the spinner dropdown to be adjusted to a particular height... Normally when I add many values it just covers the screen and then has the scrollview... But I need it to be fixed  to a particular height... Is it possible? if so, how?

Main Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager


class Main(Screen):
    pass
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass
kv=Builder.load_file("test2.kv")
screen=Manager()
screen.add_widget(Main(name="main"))

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return screen

Test().run()
```

Kv Code:

```
<Main>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        id: Fl2
        Spinner:
            id: number
            text: "Select Number"
            values: ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","ELEVEN","TWELVE"]
            size_hint: (.3,.1)
            font_size: 30
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.445,"center_y":.692}
            text_size: self.width-dp(30),None
            background_color: "#DAA628"
            background_normal: ""
            color: "#212121"
```

[Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdvfH.png)

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tM8y.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Spinner` widget allows you to specify the `dropdown_cls` that will be used to display the list of options. So, you can just specify a `dropdown_cls` that has a `max_height` property set:

```
<MyDropDown@DropDown>:
    max_height: 100

<Main>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        id: Fl2
        Spinner:
            id: number
            text: "Select Number"
            dropdown_cls: 'MyDropDown'  # specify class for DropDown 
            values: ["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN","ELEVEN","TWELVE"]
            size_hint: (.3,.1)
            font_size: 30
            pos_hint: {"center_x":.445,"center_y":.692}
            text_size: self.width-dp(30),None
            background_color: "#DAA628"
            background_normal: ""
            color: "#212121"
```

Comment: Interesting solution to extend the [`DropDown`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html?highlight=DropDown#extending-dropdown-in-kv) class by using ... how do you call that _Kv_ language feature with syntax `<Extension@Class>` ?

Comment: See [Dynamic Classes](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#dynamic-classes)